# Weather without location services, using just one fixed location

Tags: ios, ipad, geolocation, ipados, weather.app

I would like to see the current temperature on the first page (under Siri app suggestion) on iPad mini 2. But I don't like location services being on.

Is it possible just to set up one fixed location (the city I'm living in)?

It seems I cannot find such an option. But, still, I have a hope it is somewhere.

> Update: I do not have any weather app, but there is a weather widget on first page of the home screen. On the screenshot the weather widget is displayed, I templorary turned on Location Services to take a screenshot. Weather details display only when Always Allow Location Services for weather app is enabled.
>   [image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: None of the solutions given here seem to work in ios16.

Comment: @asmaier sanaz' answer has been working for me since a few days ago. The UI is pretty confusing IMO, so make sure you get everything right. (I needed to think twice until I understood that I had to click on _my location,_ for example.)

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the weather widget on the lock screen of ios 16. It doesn’t work without locating services turned on.

Answer (score 4):

Hold on your finger on weather app widget, then choose edit widget and change the location from “my location” to the specific location you want that’s on your list.
make sure you have added the location you are looking for to the weather app before this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, open weather.app and tap the bulleted list in the bottom-right.

[image]

Then click the plus button and search for your location. This will then appear at the bottom of your list. Hold your finger on it and then slide it to the top of the page (underneath your current location).

Then go to Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> Weather and click Never.

[image: image2]

Then when you return to the weather.app the location should appear at the top and be the default.

[image: image3]

Comment: I don't have any weather app installed on my ipad. I searched this, and it appears I'm not the only one with weather app missing

Comment: @qeeet there is no way to set the widget and the iPad doesn’t currently come with a weather.app

Answer (score -1):

It is indeed confusing that is similar to iPhone weather, but it is not that...

Get AccuWeather app